# Samsung: Backing up messages fails

Tags: samsung, backup, samsung-kies, samsung-galaxy-s-5-mini

I am trying to back up a Samsung S5 mini (SM-G800F, running Android 5.1.1) using either Samsung Kies or SmartSwitch.  With either program, the backup stalls for a very long time when it gets to backing up messages.  When it finally recovers, it announces that backing up messages has failed (the rest of the items are fine).

> The following categories have failed to back up due to an error.
>
> Messages — Device not responding.

Has anyone else encountered this problem?  What could be the root cause?  Is there anything I can do on the phone itself to correct this, and allow messages to get backed up as well?

In the past backup has worked correctly with the same phone.

Comment: Have you tried omitting the messages in the main backup and using a different app like SMS backup and restore to backup your messages?

Comment: @asloss Thank, you, this is useful (if incomplete: it does not restore MMS). No, I was not aware that there are other ways to backup messages. If there is no other solution I can find, I will consider this one.  I have not tried skipping message backup, but I always assumed it would avoid this error.   My main question was how to fix message backups.

Comment: It's worth giving a shot. You might have a weird message in there somewhere that is triggering a bug. Let me know. I personally don't like kies for backups. I do everything manually so that I can actually check to see if all the files are there.

Comment: @asloss Why?  Did it ever silently fail on you (i.e. claim that everything is backed up, even though it wasn't)?  If yes, that would be very disturbing. I have never had to try restoring backups ...

Comment: Yah I've had it fail on me before lost a bunch of stuff. All it ended up backing up was settings :(. Not the first time I've had a mainstream backup service fail on me. So now I make sure I have everything manually. Could just be bad luck. I also think doing it manually is faster. Just copy internal and SD card onto computer and then use SMS backup and restore for messages and  all done :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for month, I updated to the last version of smart switch today and have reboot my s8 yesterday (I have almost 25% of free space on the phone)
I gave a new chance to the backup with smart switch today and, after being stucked for almost 2 hours on "backing up message" at 18%, it finally went to the next step of the backup!
So my advice is : patience (and use an usb 3 port!)